# what is the best way to extend a CRM entity

Tags: dynamics-crm

In the crm portal, I am creating a Solution. I need a entity like orders with extra fields.  Can I create a new entity that derives off orders ?

Answer (score 0):

When you create new Entity in CRM, it will not inherit already available fields from another entity.
What you could do is, use plugin (no code) solution from Xrm Toolbox which will help you created field and relationship as fast as can.

Plugin is [Bulk Create Attributes in Dynamics CRM using Excel](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/razdynamicscrmconsultant/posts/bulk-create-attributes-in-dynamics-crm-using-excel)